# How do I translate my code from Netlogo to Netlogo Web? ('TO or TO-REPORT expected' error)

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to use Netlogo Web to open my Netlogo (Desktop version) model, but it does not seem to work. I get a 'TO or TO-REPORT expected' error when I try to upload my model. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've inserted the code below. It is supposed to model a cellular process, in which cells divide, filaments of cells branch, and cells change shape as they grow older (procedures 'divide', 'branch', 'transform'). Help please?

```
to setup
clear-all
setup-turtles
reset-ticks
  ask turtles [ set size 1 ]
end

to setup-turtles
create-threads 1

ask turtles [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set shape "line"
  set color 65
   ]
end

turtles-own [age]

to go
  add-age
  divide
  branch
  transform
  tick
  ask turtles [ set size 1 ]
end

breed [threads thread]
breed [cylinders cylinder]
breed [circles circle]


to add-age
  ask turtles [
    set age age + 1
  ifelse show-age?
[ set label age ]
[ set label "" ]
  ]
end

to divide
  ask turtles [
    if breed = threads or breed = cylinders [
    ifelse random 100 < 50
    [if (not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1) and
      (not any? other turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 10 1) and
      (not any? other turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 10 1)
      [hatch 1
        [let turn-degree (random(20) - 10)
          rt turn-degree
          fd 1
          set age age - 1
          ]
    ]
  ]
    [if (not any? other turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 180 1) and
      (not any? other turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 170 1) and
      (not any? other turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 190 1)
      [hatch 1
        [let turn-degree (170 + random(20))
          rt turn-degree
          fd 1
          set age age - 1
        ]

        ]

      ]
    ]]
end

to branch
  ask circles [
    if random 1000 < 2[
    ifelse random 100 < 50
        [if not any? other turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 90 1
      [hatch-threads 1
        [right 90
          fd 1
          set age 0
          set shape "line"]
    ]
  ]
    [if not any? other turtles-on patch-left-and-ahead 90 1
      [hatch-threads 1
        [left 90
          fd 1
          set age 0
          set shape "line"]
        ]
      ]
  ]]
end

to transform
  ask threads[
  if (age > 50) and (random 100 < 50)[
  set breed cylinders
  set shape "cylinder1"
  ]
  ]
  ask cylinders[
  if (age > 100) and (random 100 < 50) [
  set breed circles
  set shape "circle"
  ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

NetLogo Web is stricter about order of declaration (and so will be future versions of NetLogo Desktop).

Just move your `turtles-own` and `breed` statements to the top of your code and you should be all right.